# Why is NSSpeechSynthesizer not calling its delegate methods?

Tags: swift, cocoa, text-to-speech

When I call the startSpeaking(String) method on a NSSpeechSynthesizer instance, with a delegate set, speaking occurs but the following delegate methods never fire:

```
speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, 
              willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange, 
                         of string: String)

func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, 
          didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool)
```

Why? I'm using Swift 4; XCode 9.1; MacOS 10.13.1

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Compile and run the following:

```
import AppKit

class SynthDelegate: NSObject, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    var str = ""

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange, of string: String) {
        str = "spoke a word"
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
        str = "finished speaking"
    }

}

let mySpeaker = NSSpeechSynthesizer()

let myDelegate = SynthDelegate()

mySpeaker.delegate = myDelegate

mySpeaker.startSpeaking("test string to read aloud")

sleep(5) // keep alive while speaking

print(myDelegate.str)
```

**Expected Results:**

"finished speaking"

**Actual Results:**

""

## Update

Building on OOPers excellent answer, the following WORKS in a new test project:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {



    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let mySpeaker = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
        let myDelegate = SynthDelegate()
        mySpeaker.delegate = myDelegate
        mySpeaker.startSpeaking("test string to read aloud")


        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false) {_ in
            print(myDelegate.str)

        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}


class SynthDelegate: NSObject, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    var str = ""

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange, of string: String) {
        str = "spoke a word"
        print(str)
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
        str = "finished speaking"
        print(str)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing your code in the Playground? Anyway, you should never call `sleep()` in your apps including Playground code.

It prevents many activities needed to make frameworks work such as calling delegate methods. You can use `Timer` when you need to execute some code after a delay.

Testable in the Playground:

```
import AppKit

class SynthDelegate: NSObject, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    var str = ""

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange, of string: String) {
        str = "spoke a word"
        print(str)
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
        str = "finished speaking"
        print(str)
    }
}

let mySpeaker = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
let myDelegate = SynthDelegate()
mySpeaker.delegate = myDelegate
mySpeaker.startSpeaking("test string to read aloud")

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false) {_ in
    print(myDelegate.str)
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
```

Comment: Ok, that gets it working in playgrounds! Which proves (I think) it's not a bug in NSSpeechSynthesizer. What would be the equivalent for testing in an XCTestCase test?

Comment: @Mark, XCTestCase is not a good tool for testing this sort of asynchronous feature, and I have not tried working on it. If testing in an XCTestCase is a requirement for you, you'd better update your question and clarify it, as to appeal to someone who have more experience about XCTestCase.